# Error: while Using Firebase and Google Map together in android Gradle File

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

1) When I compile Firebase with Google map it does not work.

2) If I use only Firebase or Google API, then it will work for me.

3) But I want to use both things.

4) For Firebase I am using:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

5) For Google Map

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

6) It gives me error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.fc21.x86_64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

Please check below my Gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.xyz.ProjectName"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'

    // ImageLoader
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    // Map
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'

    // Spinner
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'

    // Volley
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

    //CropImage
    compile project(':CropImage')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your app for Multidex, as suggested in Naitik's answer, or include only the Google Play APIs you need. This list of APIs is in *Table 1* of the [Play Services Setup Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).  If all you need is Maps, make this change:

```
// Map
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
```

Note: If you opt for Multidex, you must also update the name of the `Application` class in your manifest, as [described here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle).

Answer (score 0):

You have enable muldidex Options using below code.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: I used it but still gives same error which i have mention in point 6

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
"compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])"
```

to

```
"provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])".
```

It resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer isn't aimed to the OP but to anybody with a similar problem.)

---

I had the same problem and was confused because I thought I setup the dependencies correctly but Android Studio was still throwing errors.

Well, after changing the order of the dependencies (Play Services before Firebase) the problem went away!

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // ...

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```